# Implicitly aliasing and extending a scala Seq

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have the following:

```
case class Bar()

trait Foo {
  def bars : Seq[Bar]
}
case class MyFoo(bars : Seq[Bar]) extends Foo

trait Foos extends Seq[Foo] {
  def bars : Seq[Bar] = this.map(_.bars).flatten
}
```

I'd like to convert objects of `Seq[MyFoo]` to `MyFoos`, preferably implicitly. How could one achieve this?

eg.

```
val foos : Foos = Seq(new MyFoo(Seq(new Bar)))
```

Comment: Do you mean to say `trait Bar; trait MyFoo { def bars: Seq[Bar] }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
  case class Bar()

  trait Foo {
    def bars : Seq[Bar]
  }
  case class MyFoo(bars : Seq[Bar]) extends Foo

  trait Foos extends Seq[Foo] {
    def bars : Seq[Bar] = this.map(_.bars).flatten
  }

  implicit def seqMyFooToMyFoos(myFoos:Seq[Foo]) = new Foos {
    def length: Int = myFoos.length

    def apply(idx: Int): Foo = myFoos(idx)

    def iterator: Iterator[Foo] = myFoos.iterator
  }

  val foos : Foos = Seq(new MyFoo(Seq(new Bar))) // Uses implicit conversion
```

**UPDATE**

This might be more of what you're looking for:

```
  trait Foos {
    def bars : Seq[Bar]
  }

  implicit def seqMyFooToMyFoos(myFoo:Seq[MyFoo]) = new Foos {
    def bars : Seq[Bar] = myFoo.map(_.bars).flatten
  }

  val foos = Seq(new MyFoo(Seq(new Bar)))

  foos.bars
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you're on scala 2.10 you can use an implicit class and drop the Foos trait:

```
  implicit class GetAllBars(myFoo:Seq[MyFoo]) {
    def bars : Seq[Bar] = myFoo.map(_.bars).flatten
  }

  val foos = Seq(new MyFoo(Seq(new Bar)))

  foos.bars
```

Comment: I updated the description, although I'm not sure it would change your answer. Does the implicit method have to create a concrete object that proxies all the Seq methods? That cannot also be inferred?

Comment: Since you're extending Seq in Foos you need to. You could optionally not extend Seq[Foo] in Foos and you would get the default Seq implementation and the bars method whenever you need to do an implicit conversion.

Comment: Since I still want the final type to have the Seq[Foo] trait, I guess I'll still need to implement those methods in all 3 cases. That's ok, although I was hoping there was a way to do something like a type alias (type Foos = Seq[Foo]) but also add a method in. Still, this answer is great, thanks!